# Playframework base url replaced as "my-backend"?

Tags: playframework-2.2

I just launched a live version of my Play!framework project (2.2.x) and even if in local (dev), the url sents to me was correct (localhost:9100), when using ./activator stage then starting it, the urls are not what they should be (the url of my app), but instead, `http://my-backend/`

I modified the application.conf to add `app.baseUrl="http://my.website.com"`, restarted the app, but still, the url is the same, `http://my-backend/`.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution :
The problem was not related to Play (even if it's ignoring the application.baseUrl), but to my nginx configuration.

I defined a `proxy_pass http://my-backend;` without configuring the proxy values.

I needed to add those at the `http` level to make it work :

```
  proxy_buffering    off;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

See the [documentation for more details](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/HTTPServer) :)